# Phonegap Android, testing in browser.

Tags: android, html, debugging, cordova

I'm building a Phonegap application. I've already made the html application, and tested it in my Windows Google Chrome browser, with no errors. I've cheked it in the navigator of my Android Phone and it is working. However, after Phonegap, I see some things are not working.

Which browser is Phonegap using? Is it not the same as the Android navigator? Can I somehow debug it?

On my Eclipse console I only see errors about Vertext shaders.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap instantiates an [Android WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) component with is not equal to the Android Browser. If your code has console.log statements you should be able to see them in LogCat tab in Eclipse.

If you want better debugging you should add [WeInRe](https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) to your project for remote debugging.

Comment: WeInRe is what I loked for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add console.log statements, which can be seen with `adb logcat` in the Terminal, or with DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

And how about this? What do you think?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en